# concurrent separation logic in Isabelle

Tags: concurrency, coq, isabelle, formal-verification, formal-methods

Is there a concurrent separation logic in Isabelle for imperative language? I found [A Separation Logic Framework for Imperative HOL](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Separation_Logic_Imperative_HOL.html) but that's not designed for concurrent imperative language like C and I wonder if there is a such framework as [Iris](https://iris-project.org/) in Coq? Maybe the framework developed by [Viktor Vafeiadis](https://people.mpi-sws.org/%7Eviktor/cslsound/) is the most relevant one. But I wonder if there is a more well-developed framework that supports better syntax and detailed features.

Comment: Peter Lammich has recently extended his LLVM stuff (https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2022/16733/pdf/LIPIcs-ITP-2022-24.pdf) to support concurrent code, so he must have some concurrent separation logic